# laravel passing parameters to route in view blade

Tags: php, laravel, database

So I'm very new to laravel and I have a filter in my website blade as follows:
goal: the user chooses a city and price from and price to and then clicks search and villas with what selected must be shown on another view! all values from the database!

I've tried to do this:

the route:

```
Route::get('/searched/{city_id}/{pricefrom}/{priceto}', [WebsiteController::class, 'search'])->name('search.clicked');
```

the controller:

```
public function index() {
    $cities = DB::table('cities')
        ->select('*')->distinct()->get();
        $users = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->get();
 
    $pricefrom = DB::table('villas')
            ->select('price')
            ->where('price', '<=', 50000)->distinct()->get();
     
    $priceto = DB::table('villas')
            ->select('price')
            ->where('price', '>', 50000)->distinct()->get();

    return view('website', compact('users','cities','pricefrom','priceto'));
}

public function search($city_id, $pricefrom, $priceto) {
    $city = City::find($city_id);
    $price = Villa::find($price);

    $citydata = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('city_id', $city_id)->get();
    $lowdata  = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('price', $pricefrom)->get();
    $highdata = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('price', $priceto)->get();
    $info = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->get();

    return view ('searched',compact('citydata','lowdata','highdata','info'))->with('city', $city )->with('price', $price);
}
```

the website view blade: here I didn't know how exactly I should pass the parameters for the route so I get an error

```
@foreach ($users as $villa)
    <form action="{{ route('search.clicked', $villa->city_id,$villa->pricefrom,$villa->priceto) }}" method="get">
        @csrf
        <select name="city" class="form-select">
            <option value=""  id="searchoption"> City </option>          
            @foreach ($cities as $city)
                <option >{{ $city->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="pricefrom" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price From </option>          
                @foreach ($pricefrom as $low)
                    <option >{{ $low->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="priceto" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price To </option>          
                @foreach ($priceto as $high)
                    <option >{{ $high->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

also Villa model

```
class Villa extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=[
        "id", "title", "description", "price", "state", "status", "city_id", "seller_id", "payment_id", 
        "created_at", "updated_at"
    ];
    public function City()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(City::class,'id','city_id');
    }
    public function Seller()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Seller::class,'id','seller_id');
    }
    public function Payment()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Payment::class,'id','payment_id');
    }
}
```

I think I have many errors I should fix And I want some help with my search bar!

I get this error:

*Missing required parameters for [Route: search.clicked] [URI: searched/{city_id}/{pricefrom}/{priceto}] [Missing parameters: pricefrom, priceto].*

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: One second you are referring things out of context. You are refencing city, low and high without defining it.

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a chapter on [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: Again can we see the error?

Comment: fyi, you have multiple `id="searchoption"` in your code - which is invalid. `id` attributes must be unique. Also change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` if you want that button to submit the form

Comment: You need a scopes query for some of this if you are going to reuse the with statement over and over

Comment: The error :  Missing required parameters for [Route: search.clicked] [URI: searched/{city_id}/{pricefrom}/{priceto}] [Missing parameters: pricefrom, priceto].  @AlexMac

Comment: Maybe create a mult dimensional array ['pricefrom' => $villa->pricefrom] forexample

Comment: I don't think you have defined a reference to that data. You have provided data with a definition with the assumption of where it belongs.

Comment: For example I could pass a social security number but not say explicitly it is a ssn. So how does the system know what you mean. Without a defined reference the system doesn't know if you are talking about an id, random number, etc..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-route-list

Comment: Do `$villa->pricefrom` and `$villa->priceto` actually exist/have a value? Did you check that? Shouldn't those be just `$pricefrom` and `$priceto`?

Comment: oh yes I tried this ->$villa->city_id,$villa->price,$villa->price , since I have one column for price in the table and edited this some definitions in the search function and I'm currently trying something and I want to ask if there's a way I can put all these variables in one ?     $city_id = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('city_id', $city_id)->get();
    $pricefrom = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('price', $pricefrom)->get();
    $priceto = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->where('price', $priceto)->get();   @AlexMac

Comment: You need to define a key to that value bud. As of right now, you don't. You are passing arbitrary data to the view without giving the view a point of reference through a variable.

Comment: ['cities' => $villa->cities, 'priceform' => $villas->priceform ...etc.

Comment: You are currently doing loops over data that is potentially not connected. Like User::find($user_id). City::all(), etc... and looping over them not in the same scope

Comment: like you blade seems like it should have a foreach of $villa->cities as $city

Comment: and your search function maybe great but in the code you have shared you are not leveraging it. your finds could also be handled by route model bindings. You are also not leveraging the eloquent orm.

Comment: I see, I need solution suggestions please @AlexMac

Comment: okay, but I will get hammered for "guessing"

Comment: We needed to see that city object...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
            <form action="{{ route('search.clicked', [$villa->city_id,$villa->pricefrom,$villa->priceto]) }}" method="get">
```

According to route function second parameter should be string or array. String or Array if you're passing only 1 & array if you are passing 2 or more.

```
 function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
```

Comment: Sorry what you are saying makes sense but without context, misleading

Comment: It will throw error the way he wrote it if it's not an array 100%, Either way in this point or later this will throw an error.

Comment: Ya I redacted what I said an editted

Comment: Just because he is foreaching over a model, object, etc... The blade file has no context of city etc..

Comment: Whoops overlooked that piece... My bad he did

Comment: Ehh kinda or not, like you are foreaching in two different context

Comment: I want to see if this works because this has a huge point. However the code by the op could use some improvement

Comment: I've tried it and I got this error:  Missing required parameters for [Route: search.clicked] [URI: searched/{city_id}/{pricefrom}/{priceto}] [Missing parameters: pricefrom, priceto].  @workservice

Answer (score 0):

BLADE FILE:

```
@foreach ($users as $villa)
    <form action="{{ route('search.clicked', $villa->city_id,$villa->pricefrom,$villa->priceto) }}" method="get">
        @csrf
        <select name="city" class="form-select">
            <option value=""  id="searchoption"> City </option>          
            @foreach ($cities as $city)
                <option >{{ $city->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="pricefrom" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price From </option>          
                @foreach ($pricefrom as $low)
                    <option >{{ $low->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="priceto" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price To </option>          
                @foreach ($priceto as $high)
                    <option >{{ $high->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach ($users as $villa)
    <form action="{{ route('search.clicked', ['city_id' => $villa->city_id, 'pricfrom' => $villa->pricefrom, 'priceto' =>$villa->priceto]) }}" method="get">
        @csrf
        <select name="city" class="form-select">
            <option value=""  id="searchoption"> City </option>          
            @foreach ($villa->cities as $city)
                <option >{{ $city->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="pricefrom" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price From </option>          
                @foreach ($villa->pricefrom as $low)
                    <option >{{ $low->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <select name="priceto" class="form-select">
                <option value=""  id="searchoption"> Price To </option>          
                @foreach ($villa->priceto as $high)
                    <option >{{ $high->price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: There that may work

Comment: Then in your from action

Comment: ```<form action="{{ route('search.clicked', [$villa->city_id,$villa->pricefrom,$villa->priceto]) }}" method="get">```

Comment: That doesn't work make your form action pass in indexex that are defining. 

            <form action="{{ route('search.clicked', 
['city_id' => $villa->city_id,
'pricfrom' => $villa->pricefrom,
'priceto' =>$villa->priceto]) }}" method="get">

Comment: Thank u! But I should point to that I don't have columns in the villas table called pricefrom or priceto , I only have the column price, and maybe for that after I tried your code the same error appears: Missing required parameters for [Route: search.clicked] [URI: searched/{city_id}/{pricefrom}/{priceto}] [Missing parameters: pricefrom, priceto]. I've tried to put price instead of pricefrom and priceto the error didn't appear but on the route I can see that it took the same value for both priceto and pricefrom which is wrong  @Alex

Comment: Okay we are getting somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need add to route :

```php
    <form action="{{ route('search.clicked',$object->first()->city_id,$model->first()->pricefrom,$model->first()->priceto) }}" method="get">
```

Comment: thank u, object and model refers to what exactly, sorry I'm a beginner @Tural

Comment: Thanks dude nice. saved me looking at this more indepth. God bless. I have to start my actual job now.

Comment: @sari, next time you ask a question provide relationships or erd because I see that you were foreach over stuff but didn't know the relationship or if it was a mistake.

Comment: and I really didn't feel comfortable posting an answer given that unknown, but was running out of time.

Comment: there is not any problem . I am glad If this helpful to you